# Creating the Tetris shapes in Java as classes extending Area or Shape

Tags: java, shapes, area, tetris

I am working on writing the Tetris game myself using Java. I am not using any tutorials already containing the code, because I want to try to decompose it myself and see how far I can take it.

So far, not so good. I have stumbled upon the creation on the Shapes.
My idea would be to either:
1. have each basic shape (like the L, the cube, the boat) as separate classes extending or implementing Area or Shape so that I can use it as an argument for `g2.fill(LShape)`.
2. each class would have some sort of state variable describing the rotation position, but that's next challenge, figuring out the rotation..

So for Step 1, I have written so far the following drafts of the LShape class:

Draft a):

```
public class LShape implements Shape{
private Rectangle[][] poc;
private int rotationState;  

public LShape() {
    rotationState = 0;
    poc = new Rectangle[3][3];
    poc[0][0] = new Brick(INITIAL_X - BRICK, INITIAL_Y, BRICK); 
    poc[1][0] = new Brick(INITIAL_X - BRICK, INITIAL_Y + BRICK, BRICK);
    poc[2][0] = new Brick(INITIAL_X - BRICK, INITIAL_Y + 2 * BRICK, BRICK);
    poc[2][1] = new Brick(INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y + 2 * BRICK, BRICK);
}      
}
//.....all the Shape's methods which I'm not overriding cause I don't know how
```

In the main class I am calling in the paint() method:
    `g2.fill(lShape); // where lShape is a LShape object;`
And the trouble is an exception is thrown about the `getPathIterator()`

OR Draft b):

```
public class LShape extends Area{

public LShape () {

    add(new Area(new Brick(INITIAL_X - BRICK, INITIAL_Y, BRICK)));
    exclusiveOr(new Area(new Brick(INITIAL_X - BRICK, INITIAL_Y + BRICK, BRICK)));
    exclusiveOr(new Area(new Brick(INITIAL_X - BRICK, INITIAL_Y + 2 * BRICK, BRICK)));
    exclusiveOr(new Area(new Brick(INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y + 2 * BRICK, BRICK)));
}
}
```

In this case when I call the `g2.fill(lShape)` there is no exception and the Shape is drawn, only that I don't know how to move it. Parts of the Area are the Brick objects which are Rectangles, so I could try to access the `setLocation` method on each Brick in the Area, but  I don't know how to access it.

So I guess I need help either to figure out how to make the Shape implementation of a Tetris Shape not to throw the exceptions, meaning implementing all the required methods and actually showing up on the JPanel..and then I will worry about the rotation.
OR figure out how to make the Area extension of a Tetris Shape to move around.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

When rendering shapes, you can to use `Graphics#translate` or `AffineTransform` on a `Graphics2D` instance or use `Shape#getPathIterator(AffineTransform)`, but that takes more work as you need to wrap back into a shape

For example...

```
// Call me lazy, this preserves the state of the current Graphics
// context and makes it easy to "restore" it, simply by disposing
// of this copy...
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
g2d.translate(x, y);
g2d.fill(shape);
// Restores the state of the `Graphics` object...
g2d.dispose();
```

If you want to continue using `Area`, take a look at [`Area#createTransformedArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#createTransformedArea%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform%29) which should allow you to use an `AffineTransform` to transform the `Area`, but it returns an `Area` making it significantly easier to use then `Shape#getPathIterator`.

It also means you can generate a compound transformation (rotate, translate, etc) and generate a `Area` that represents the transformation...

Comment: Ok, so I guess I will go with the Area extension of a Tetris Shape and  rely on the Graphics#translate. I gave it a go and it did move it. I will play some more and experiment, but I should be good. Thanks a lot